# the Current code only returns a value of 0 when run

Tags: java, class, methods, zero

This is the Console. When entering values after the user decides what to calculate. The values that return from the class are zero. I have private variables, with accessors and mutators. I don't know what the reason for this is. Any ideas?? Please!!!

```
public class Console {

    public static final int USER_CHOIDE_VOLTAGE = 1;
    public static final int USER_CHOIDE_AMPERAGE = 2;
    public static final int USER_CHOIDE_RESISTANCE = 3;
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Creates a Circuit Object
        Circuit myCircuit = new Circuit();
        // Creates a Scanner Object to get input from user
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Holds input from user
        int userChoice;
System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("This system will calculate the ");
        System.out.println("\tVoltage, Amperage, or Resistance ");
        System.out.println("\tgiven the other two values using Ohms Law.");
        System.out.println("\n");

        // Ask user what to calculate, if it is not one
        // of the options, ask again(while-do loop)
        do {
            System.out.println("Which value would you like to calculate?");
            System.out.println("\t1. Voltage");
            System.out.println("\t2. Resistane");
            System.out.println("\t3. Amperage");
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("Please select 1, 2, or 3");
            userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

            //Switch follows cases for what the user would
            // like to calculate
        switch (userChoice) {
            case USER_CHOIDE_VOLTAGE:
                // Gets Amperage from User
                System.out.println("Please enter the Amperage:");
                // Sets Amperage value
                myCircuit.setAmperage(keyboard.nextDouble());
                // Gets Resistance from User
                System.out.println("Please enter the Resistance:");
                // Sets Resistance value
                myCircuit.setResistance(keyboard.nextDouble());
                // Returns Value for voltage from method
                System.out.println("The value of Voltage is: "
                        + myCircuit.getVoltage());
                break;

            case USER_CHOIDE_AMPERAGE:
                // Gets Voltage from User
                System.out.println("Please enter the Voltage:");
                myCircuit.setVoltage(keyboard.nextDouble());
                // Gets Resistance from User
                System.out.println("Please enter the Resistance:");
                // Sets Resistance value
                myCircuit.setResistance(keyboard.nextDouble());
                // Returns Value for Amperage from method
                System.out.println("The value of Amperage is: "
                        + myCircuit.getAmperage());
                break;

            case USER_CHOIDE_RESISTANCE:
                // Gets Amperage from User
                System.out.println("Please enter the Amperage:");
                // Sets Amperage value
                myCircuit.setAmperage(keyboard.nextDouble());
                // Gets Voltage from User
                System.out.println("Please enter the Voltage:");
                myCircuit.setVoltage(keyboard.nextDouble());
                // Returns Value for Resistance from method
                System.out.println("The value of Resistance is: "
                        + myCircuit.getResistance());
                break;
            // Do Nothing Since do while loop takes care of this option
            default:
            }
        } while (userChoice != USER_CHOIDE_VOLTAGE
            && userChoice != USER_CHOIDE_AMPERAGE
            && userChoice != USER_CHOIDE_RESISTANCE);

        System.exit(0);
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

This is the Class

```
public class Circuit {

    private double voltage, resistance, amperage;

    public double getVoltage() {
        return voltage;
    }

    public double getResistance() {
        return resistance;
    }

    public double getAmperage() {
        return amperage;
    }

    public void setVoltage(double pVoltage) {
        voltage = pVoltage;
    }

    public void setResistance(double pResistance) {
        resistance = pResistance;
    }

    public void setAmperage(double pAmperage) {
        amperage = pAmperage;
    }

    public void calcVoltage() {
        voltage = amperage * resistance;
    }

    public  void calcResistance() {
        resistance = voltage / amperage;
    }
    public void calcAmperage() {
        amperage = voltage / resistance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please to make it easier for us to help you, post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . In other words, code we can run to test it. Note that we may not have the `bp.Circuit` library.

Comment: Could you remove everything that is irrelevant to your problem? This includes trivial getters/setters and comments.

Comment: the bp.Circuit is below. Sorry

Comment: Wish I could +1 for removing all the javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling your `calcSomething()` methods, therefore, you are not computing anything and just returning (by `getSomething()`) the values without modifications. Before continuing, please check your print statements, I think they should look like

```
System.out.println("\t1. Voltage");
System.out.println("\t2. Amperate");
System.out.println("\t3. Resistance");
```

since you declared your constants:

```
public static final int USER_CHOIDE_VOLTAGE = 1;
public static final int USER_CHOIDE_AMPERAGE = 2;
public static final int USER_CHOIDE_RESISTANCE = 3;
```

Continuing with the explanation, let's say the input is `2`, so the `switch` would enter the  `case USER_CHOIDE_AMPERAGE`, here is the problem, you must compute the "amperage" by calling `myCircuit.calcAmperage()`:

```
case USER_CHOIDE_AMPERAGE:
    System.out.println("Please enter the Voltage:");
    myCircuit.setVoltage(keyboard.nextDouble());
    System.out.println("Please enter the Resistance:");
    myCircuit.setResistance(keyboard.nextDouble());
    myCircuit.calcAmperage(); // ADD THIS LINE
    System.out.println("The value of Amperage is: " + myCircuit.getAmperage());
    break;
```

You must do similar changes to the other `swith-cases`.

Answer (score 1):

You never actually call any of the Circuit classes `calc...()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the appropriate `calc` method before your final print statements.

For example, when `userChoice` is `USER_CHOIDE_VOLTAGE`:

```
        case USER_CHOIDE_VOLTAGE:
            // Gets Amperage from User
            System.out.println("Please enter the Amperage:");
            // Sets Amperage value
            myCircuit.setAmperage(keyboard.nextDouble());
            // Gets Resistance from User
            System.out.println("Please enter the Resistance:");
            // Sets Resistance value
            myCircuit.setResistance(keyboard.nextDouble());
            // *** Add the following line to your program. ***
            myCircuit.calcVoltage();
            // Returns Value for voltage from method
            System.out.println("The value of Voltage is: "
                    + myCircuit.getVoltage());
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem

For example

you are calling `myCircuit.getVoltage()`

and in the function you are not calculating anything

```
public double getVoltage() {
    return voltage;
}
```

instead call

`myCircuit.calcVoltage()`

Comment: I went ahead and added the myCircuit.calcVoltage();, myCircuit.calcResistance();, myCircuit.calcAmperage();, after the user enters the last input before the returning statements. That should do it

Answer (score 0):

You can call your cal.. Method in every Getter method like..

```
  public double getAmperage() {
    calcAmperage();
    return amperage;
}



 public double getVoltage() {
    calcVoltage();
    return voltage;
}
```